# ReactiveList.AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection) fires for each item in collection

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Using ReactiveUI 6.0.0 and having

```
var myReactiveList = new ReactiveList<SomeType>();

// [...] later I subscribe to the list:

myReactiveList.Changed.Subsribe(_ => 
{
     // this will be invoked 10 times, once for each item
     // in "myList" added through AddRange(...) below 
     // eg. count will increase from 1 to 10 on each call
     var test = myReactiveList.ToList();
     int count = test.Count;
});

// Now I add a couple of items at once 
// (eg. aList is a List<SomeType> with say 10 items)
// This will fire 10 times
myReactiveList.AddRange(aList);
```

**Question:** Is this expected behaviour? And if so, what should I do instead to subscribe so that my observer only gets notified once if a collection (`AddRange(..)`) is added?

**Edit:** Setting `myReactiveList.ResetChangeThreshold = 0;` did the trick.

**Edit 2:** There IS actually documentation for this (and other reactive stuff), just buried in ReactiveUI's `docs` branch, and in the `docs` folder in that branch: [ReactiveList](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/docs/docs/basics/reactive-list.md)

So, in order to achieve what I originally wanted, I would do this:

```
using (myReactiveList.SuppressChangeNotifications()) {
    myReactiveList.AddRange(aList);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `ResetChangeThreshold` property.  By default, change suppression will only be triggered in `AddRange` if you add more than 10 items **and** the number of new items is 30% of the original.  For details, see [the source](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L541).

Comment: @cardinal Just note that it still will fire each item if you only add 9 items :)

Comment: ups. In my real code I actually had 44 items, not 10 (I just took the number 10 at random, for this sample code... I'll take a closer look to ReactiveList's source then :-)

Comment: Yep - this is an optimization designed for views that bind to the list; if the list changes too much, we should send a single Reset to tell the view to reload the entire list from scratch instead of processing multiple Adds